# Warranty on Nexus 7

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-7, warranty

I just won an auction on the Nexus 7. The seller claims that he doens't have the original sales receipt but says I will be able to sign up for the warranty online with the registration & activation of the Nexus. So, how does this exactly work and will this warranty be of the international type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [contact ASUS](http://support.asus.com/Hotlines.aspx?SLanguage=en) directly.

[Google play's support page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2662734) says:

> Nexus 7 limited warranty
>   The Nexus 7 is manufactured by ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASUS provides a limited 12 month warranty for the Nexus 7. Please refer to the warranty card in the Nexus 7 packaging or review ASUS' limited warranty details.
>
> If your Nexus 7 was purchased from Google Play, please contact Google
>   customer support for service on the ASUS limited 12 month warranty. If
>   your Nexus 7 wasn't purchased from Google Play or you're looking for
>   out of warranty repair service, please contact ASUS directly.